# Picking the correct component from a generic typed factory

Tags: c#, generics, castle-windsor, typed-factory-facility

### Solution

see @samy answer, but it was the open class that was incorrect. I just need to change:

```
  StockDelayModule<T> : ModulePartBase<T>, IModulePart<T> where T : StockDelay
```

to

```
  StockDelayModule : ModulePartBase<StockDelay>, IModulePart<StockDelay>
```

then all references to T within `StockDelayModule` to `StockDelay`

The `AsFactory()` registration then works fine and can resolve the correct component.

---

I've been reluctant to post this question as I wanted to figure it out, but I also don't want a barrage of "duplicate" comments, but I'm at a loss.

I've got an interface

```
public interface IModulePart<T>
{
    IResponse<T> Create(CreateRequest request, IPromise<T> promise);
    IResponse Delete(DeleteRequest request, IPromise<T> promise);
    IResponse<T> Read(ReadRequest request, IPromise<T> promise);
    IResponse<T> Update(UpdateRequest request, IPromise<T> promise);
}
```

with several implementations which vary based on `T`. For instance:

```
WebUrlModule<T> : IModulePart<T> where T : WebUrl
StockDelayModule<T> : IModulePart<T> where T : StockDelay
```

I've got my installer, which is registering the components fine:

```
 Classes.FromAssemblyInDirectory(new AssemblyFilter("bin"))
                .BasedOn(typeof(IModulePart<>))                   
                .WithService.Base()
                .LifestyleTransient()
```

I've got my factory:

```
public interface IModulePartFactory
{
    IModulePart<T> FindModulePartFor<T>(); 
}
```

There is then my factory selector which is running, overriding `GetComponentType` from `DefaultTypedFactoryComponentSelector`:

```
protected override Type GetComponentType(MethodInfo method, object[] arguments)
{
    if (method.Name == "FindModulePartFor")
    {
         return typeof(IModulePart<>).MakeGenericType(method.GetGenericArguments()[0]);
    }

    return base.GetComponentType(method, arguments);
}
```

---

Every thing seems to *look* mostly correct, and when debugging (using `WebUrl`) the generic type is something like `IModulePart'1[[WebUrl, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]`

However, as you may have guessed, it isn't working. If I make a call with `StockDelay`, it resolves fine because I think it's returning the first registered component, but when using `WebUrl`, it breaks. I say `StockDelay` works, but I think it's more just the case that it's returning anything (first matching component), rather than selecting the *correct* component.

The message I get is:
`Types WebUrl don't satisfy generic constraints of implementation type StockDelayModule'1 of component 'StockDelayModule'1'. This is most likely a bug in your code.`

Anything glaringly obvious to anyone, or suggestions as to anything that might be incorrect? Or am I just trying something that isn't possible!? Thanks.

---

#### Update

If I change my classes to abstract and implement them with a derived class that isn't generic it works. So it leads me to think it's just a small configuration in castle related to the generic that's meaning it isn't resolving correctly. Ideas?:

```
public class StockDelayModule : StockDelayModulePart<StockDelay> { }
public abstract class StockDelayModulePart<T> : ModulePartBase<T>, IModulePart<T> { }
```

Comment: if I change my installer to be `Named` with the implmentation name, removing '1 - so `WebUrlModule`, and then resolve using `GetComponentName` and the generic argument name + "Module", it works - but I don't really like this approach.

Comment: Would you please paste the code from your component selector? Because there should be the logic of selecting the proper component.

Comment: It's pretty much as I've already said, but I will update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the custom resolver, because Castle will try to resolve the factory call depending on the return type. Unless there are some other things you need, the following should be sufficient to resolve a `IModulePart<T>` depending on `T`:

```
public class WebUrl { }
public class StockDelay { }
public interface IModulePart<T> { }
public class WebUrlModule : IModulePart<WebUrl> { }
public class StockDelayModule : IModulePart<StockDelay> { }
public interface IModulePartFactory
{
    IModulePart<T> FindModulePartFor<T>();
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = new Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer();
        container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();

        container.Register(
            Classes.FromAssemblyInThisApplication()
                .BasedOn(typeof(IModulePart<>))
                .WithService.Base()
                .LifestyleTransient(),
            Component.For<IModulePartFactory>().AsFactory()
        );

        var factory = container.Resolve<IModulePartFactory>();
        var moduleForWebUrl = factory.FindModulePartFor<WebUrl>(); 
        // type is WebUrlModule
        var moduleForStockDelay = factory.FindModulePartFor<StockDelay>();
        // type is StockDelayModule
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right in that it does work with just `AsFactory()` without my custom component selector when using derived class (see my update), however I still have the same error when using the generic class directly - `Types WebUrl don't satisfy generic constraints of implementation type StockDelayModulePart'1 of component StockDelayModulePart'1. This is most likely a bug in your code.`

Comment: Could you show us the whole class/interface/registration/resolution code in a block? I have a feeling we are missing a piece, most notably with the `ModulePartbase`. And with the notation `WebUrlModule<T> : IModulePart<T> where T : WebUrl` which should simply be `WebUrlModule : IModulePart<WebUrl>`

Comment: The `ModulePartBase` is simply just a base class as helper for for creating `IResponse<T>` and `IPromise<T>`. However I've just realised from what you've said that I don't need my derived classes to be open, I've removed that and the generic on the base and interface (and references in the class) and it's all working fine. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I should have mentioned it first, but I didn't want to presume about your code before repro-ing the problem; often people will sanitize their code before posting which can lead to small incoherences. Happy this could help!

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try to override the other method :

> protected override string GetComponentName(MethodInfo method, object[] arguments)

What the container registrations say? You can check the registration and the section with the misconfigured components.

Although overriding this method may partially solve the problem it does not solve the root of the problem - it is another way to check if you have misconfigured your component.

Comment: I've tried that route already and it doesn't seem to make a difference. It still resolves the incorrect component. It is a "potentially misconfigured component", but I think that's to due to having dynamic parameters on it more than anything else. As I've added (edit) on my question though, creating non-generic derived classes of my class works fine... :-/